# Why do calling two WITH clauses, with one calling the other, not work?

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Simple practical problem: I have a table, `const_a`, that contains a humongous amount of rows and columns.
When I call `SELECT A, B, C FROM const_a WHERE restrictive_conditions` I obtain all the rows I wish to work on and the only columns I need.

The rows are grouped by the column `A`, values are in the column `C`, and options are in the column `B`. My goal is to get all the `C` values from all the `A` groups who have at least one row where `B` has a certain value, let's say `'v'`.

The first query will be:

```
SELECT C FROM const_a
WHERE restrictive_conditions
AND A IN (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM const_a WHERE B LIKE 'v')
```

`B LIKE 'v'` is not very restrictive over `const_a`, and I do not want to repeat the `restrictive_conditions` in the `SELECT DISTINCT` so I'll use a `WITH` clause, like this:

```
WITH tmp_a AS (SELECT A, B, C FROM const_a WHERE restrictive_conditions)
SELECT C FROM tmp_a
WHERE A IN (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM tmp_a WHERE B LIKE 'v')
```

This query works, in a reasonable time, and returns the expected values.

The last `SELECT DISTINCT` is quite obscure in the context of the query, so for ease of understanding, I add a second `WITH`:

```
WITH tmp_a AS (SELECT A, B, C, FROM const_a WHERE restrictive_conditions),
tmp_b AS (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM tmp_a WHERE B LIKE 'v')
SELECT C FROM tmp_a WHERE A IN (SELECT A FROM tmp_b) ;
```

I give `tmp_a` and `tmp_b` meaningful names, here it will be similar to `minimal_range` and `valid_groups`, and call it a day but when I then try to run this query I keep getting disconnection errors that according to my searches indicate that Oracle crashed on its own in the background, without telling me.

I have tried and tested all manners of aliasing, used an `INNER JOIN` instead of the `WHERE ... IN ...`, but no luck; when I have two or more `WITH` clauses, one call another, and I call them together, it crashes. Depending on the way I build it, I also got empty results (although trying the different parts independently gave the expected results, as if a `WITH` clause emptied itself after being called in another). This is not a desired outcome.

In this instance I can use a different query but I would like to know how to use nested `WITH` clauses together. Others might benefit from this as well.

Can someone please explain why this does not work? I hope it is a simple syntax error but neither the console nor the Oracle SQL developer Client give any such indication, just loss of connection. Does anyone have a solution?

This is done with Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.3.0, according to the sqlplus command. I have typed this all so the error does not come from a simple typo, but thank you for any correction.

Edit: I must specify, I also added `/*+ MATERIALIZE */` after the `SELECT` in my `WITH` clauses, and it didn't do anything different.

Edit 2 : Never mind, I thought I found the emptied clause.

Edit 3 : Hello everybody, I found the solution, or rather I should say I found the problem.
I did have more than one '`C`' column, and one of these was a CLOB column. I found strange that MatBailie's code worked when I typed it, but not mine, so I really tried building back my own query by changing his little by little, and the moment I asked for additional value columns, it stopped working, and trying to add one or the other showed that my CLOB (and I tested, same with BLOB) column was the column too much. I'll have to use a different query.

Since MatBailie was correct, I'll accept his solution. Thanks APC for your help as well, although I didn't get to try it. I have a feeling the trace would have hinted towards the correct solution.

Comment: If you're getting disconnection errors there maybe useful information in the Alert Log, or maybe trace files. Have you looked at those? Depending on your organisation, you may need a DBA to help with access to the pertinent directory.

Comment: Hello @APC , thank you for commenting. I don't know how to access these logs, but I will search, thank you. When I type the difficult query in the console of sqlplus, I get the error "ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel ". It worked though when I created tables and executed the parts one at a time (then deleted the tables), accessing the rows and displaying the results is possible.

Comment: ORA-03113 should trigger the writing of diagnostic information to the alert log. [This article will help you find it](https://csl-oracle.blogspot.com/2013/01/finding-location-of-oracle-alert-log.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work as written, see this test:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/49782/10

I think, however, that you can simplify the computation involve a little, by using Analytic Functions instead of `IN()`...

```
WITH
  restrict_and_check AS
(
  SELECT
    A, B, C,
    MAX(CASE WHEN B = 'v' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY A
      )
        AS a_includes_b_that_equals_v
  FROM
    const_a
  WHERE
    restrictive_condition
)
SELECT
  C
FROM
  restrict_and_check
WHERE
  a_includes_b_that_equals_v = 1
```

The `MAX() OVER ()` is like a sub-query and with an aggregate function.

In the above example it partitions the data by the column `A`, and passes all the rows with the same value to the function.

The function in this case is `MAX(CASE WHEN B = 'v' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, which will return a 1 if any of the incoming rows have `B = 'v'`, other wise it return `0`.

It's a bit like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  a_data_set
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN B = 'v' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS a_includes_b_that_equals_v
  FROM
    a_data_set
  GROUP BY
    A
)
  a_check
    ON a_check.A = a_data_set.A
```

For a clearer explanation look up Analytic Functions or Windowed Functions.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. Can you tell me what `MAX(...) OVER (PARTITION BY ...)` does? This is a different query altogether, so it might work in my case, but it does not explain how to use multiple `WITH`.

Comment: @LJISAM - I added a few notes on analytic functions, and added a demo that shows that your query SHOULD have worked, and compares it to my answer.